# Is it "placing her hand in his" or "placing her hand on his"?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-usage

- "Placing her hand **in** his" has [2K](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=%22placing%20her%20hand%20in%20his%22&rlz=1C1ASUC_enTW628TW628&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZwJTEpaDTAhUGT7wKHfgDDHsQ_AUIDCgF&biw=1920&bih=974) hits on Google Books.
- "Placing her hand **on** his" has [14K](https://www.google.com.tw/search?rlz=1C1ASUC_enTW628TW628&biw=1920&bih=974&tbm=bks&q=%22placing%20her%20hand%20on%20his%22&oq=%22placing%20her%20hand%20on%20his%22&gs_l=serp.3...44061.44209.0.44292.3.3.0.0.0.0.137.178.1j1.2.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..3.0.0.Ptzgl3MJdWk).

Both had a lot of results. Are both equally correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phrases are valid. I imagine that sometimes they can mean the same thing, but my first impression was that "placing her hand in his" sounds like they are about to hold hands, like this:

[image]

I thought "placing her hand on his" sounds like she placed her hand on top of his, like this:
[image]